# JQuery, CSS full width elements not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a little problem. I am using JQuery to set an element to a full width and height of the page and calc() function in CSS to fill that element with other two elements. But there is a problem, when I try to resize there appears to be a vertical line that is probably space for the scrollbar although there is no scrollbar present, just the space for it. And it occurs only in specific situations, usually when I resize the window to a smaller size. Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/yr4uz3p5/.

HTML file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/colors.css"/>
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <section>

            </section>
            <nav>

            </nav>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS file:

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    color: #00ff00;
    background-color: #000000;
}

section {
    min-width: 300px;
    width: calc(100% - 300px);
    height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    float: left;
}

nav {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
    float: left;
}

div {
    min-width: 300px;
}

body {
    min-width: 300px;
}
```

JS file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div").width($(window).width());
    $("div").height($(window).height());
});

$(window).resize(function() {
    $("div").width($(window).width());
    $("div").height($(window).height());
});
```

The general idea about this is that I want navigation to be located on the right side with the fixed width of 300px and I want data displayed on the left part.

Thanks in advance for help!

**EDIT:**

**I have found the better way, since these elements will always have the height same as the window, I have placed overflow: hidden for body and now the black line will never show up...**

Comment: Also, I have tried doing the same thing but targeting individual elements (section and nav) for both width and height (making their heights equal to $(window).height() and width to $(window).width() - 300 for section) and removing div element, the same thing happened.

Comment: calc is experimental and not fully supported in all browsers, notably IE has problems when a child element has the same property and many webkit properties need the -webkit- vendor prefix. see if adding vendor prefixes solves your problem. (also note, its listed as buggy on MDN docs) 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc
http://caniuse.com/#search=calc

Comment: I have tried setting width and height without calc(), with JQuery... And the same happens...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try additionally setting `div` `min-width` to `calc(100%)`

```
div {
    min-width:calc(100%);
}
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yr4uz3p5/1/

Comment: Awesome, this solved the problem, but I would still like to know why this was happening... If you could enlighten me, that would be great... :)

Comment: At http://jsfiddle.net/yr4uz3p5/1/ `css` loaded before `jQuery` loaded; `calc()` http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-values-3/#calc-notation set `min-width:calc(100%)` of containing element, continue calculating expression provided `100%`, independent of `.resize()` event;  `float:left` set on `nav` element does not _"touches the edge of it's containing box or another floated element."_; sibling `section` set `float:left`? see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float At http://jsfiddle.net/yr4uz3p5/1/ `min-width:300px` not calculating `min-width` between `resize`,wrapping float elements?